# Is there a metadata exclusion filter for the SVN DIFF command?

Tags: svn, version-control, properties, diff, metadata

I use SVN as the source control system, and I wonder how to compare directories while ignoring any metadata differences. Is there a way to tell `svn diff` to compare only the actual content and ignore any metadata?

I mean metadata like SVN properties, etc. that don't affect the file content. Assume file X has an additional property in branch B compared to trunk T. Unfortunately it will show up in 'svn diff T B' even though the actual content of file X is the same.

I look for something like this:

```
svn diff https://example.org/tags/v1 https://example.org/tags/v2 -x -ignore-metadata --summarize
```

**Update:** I partially solved this by diff'ing directly on the filesystem instead of using the SVN tools. See my own answer below...

Comment: What do you mean by metadata?

Comment: "SVN properties" is a better word to describe it. I fixed my post to clarify this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be no way to get this done using the svn built-in tools. How I solved it: 
Export both trees and diff them diretly on the filesystem using your favourite diff tool. That's somehow the only way to get this done :/

Answer (score 25):

You can pass the svn diff output through 'filterdiff --clean' to remove any extraneous lines including property changes.

Comment: Working as advertised - great! A hint for Debian / Ubuntu users: if `filterdiff` is not on your system, you can install it via `apt-get install patchutils`.

Comment: Newer versions of svn (tested on 1.9.3) provide a builtin way to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50515644/5749914 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/18984711/5749914.

Answer (score 11):

If you use the `--summarize` option, then property changes are indicated in the second rather than the first column.

I.e.,

```
M  URL  -- indicates content change
 M URL  -- property change
MM URL  -- content and property change
```

It is a bit easier to grep. I guess you could have a two-stage process if you want a full diff - first use summarize to find files with content change, then diff them.

Answer (score 7):

Found this while searching through the svn help docs

```
svn diff --patch-compatible
```

It's the same as running

```
svn diff --show-copies-as-adds --ignore-properties
```

Answer (score 6):

Nice tip from JosephWatkins.

Here is the command for the grep-junior-users:

```
svn diff A B --summarize | grep '^. '
```

The grep looks for a space as the second character on the line.

Comment: Sorry. It must be 

svn diff A B --summarize | grep -v '^ '

All Lines starting with a space must be hidden, because there where only property changes on files.

Comment: This does not handle cases where file content *and* properties are both changed, or where something else, like locking, happened to the file and the file is modified.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`svn diff --ignore-properties`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.ignore_properties). That's Subversion's built-in method to do differencing of the content only. It ignores any changes to the properties of the items.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19826927)

Comment: Does it not? The author's question asked how to get `svn diff` to ignore all subversion properties when doing a diff. That's precisely what `svn --ignore-properties` does. Maybe I should have worded it better as an answer. I'll try to do so in the future.

Comment: @ryadavilli why are stackoverflow reviewers so obtuse?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a single command that does all this. Say you want to find all (non-property) diffs for all files in the currently directory between revision 54833 and 57215. This command should do it:

```
svn diff -r 54833:57215 --summarize | egrep -v '^ |^D|^A' | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs svn diff -r 54833:57215
```

NB: It only diffs modified files - not added or deleted files.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a script to do this, after I couldn't find one online.

The script removes the data based on an array of regular expressions entered at the top of the script.  Currently, it is set up to filter out the properties changes, but it can remove any change that matches a series of regular expressions.

Just pipe the output of `svn diff` to the script, after you set the script.  I put the filters in the script instead of parameters because I always run the same filters.

I released it as GPLv2.

[clean_svn_diff.bash](http://www.scottgrizzard.com/2009/script-that-filters-svn-diff-output-removing-entires-based-on-metadata-or-file-names/)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but a simple 'svn diff | grep -iv "stuff to ignore"' would be a workaround.

Comment: The whole diff comes only as a huge amount of text, I would have to manually parse it to filter out all 'svn property added'-like changes. No easy task I can get done using grep unfortunately.

Answer (score -6):

You can set the [svn:ignore](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html) property on files and directories you want svn diff to ignore.

Comment: I don't want to ignore specific directories or files, it's about ignoring differing properties (aka metadata) of the same files. Assume file X has an additional property in branch B compared to trunk T. It will show up in svn diff even though the actual content is the same.