# SVN status, ignore props?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is there a way to ignore property changes using `svn status` à la https://stackoverflow.com/a/1514914/5749914 (for SVN diff)?

I have a HUGE number of properties changes in a merge of several revisions and I want to see what's going on. Using TortoiseSVN isn't good enough because of all the properties changes clogging up the diff. Compounding this problem is that the `ignoreprops` [flag](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html) only works for diffs on individual files, or so it seems.

I'm afraid even reverting all the properties changes would just waste time when reverting several revisions (or possibly break something??), although that is definitely an option.

It'd be so nice if there will *some* tool that could show the diff without properties.